# Fetch and save data-uri from string

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, fetch

I'm trying to fetch only the data-uri from a string.

The PHP

```
$result = '<div class="search-hit__image" data-uri="http://foobar.com/s/resources/images/70474/small/foo/bar.jpg">
<div class="search-hit__product">Foobar
</div>
</div>';
```

How can I with php use preg_replace (or something) to only fetch the data-uri?

I want the result to be:

```
$result = 'http://foobar.com/s/resources/images/70474/small/foo/bar.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a simple string as your example, use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match('/data-uri="([^"]+)/', $str, $match);
```

The uri will be in `$match[1]`.

If your string is much more complex, use DomDocument.